# how to toggle a css class on list items when a click event is triggered using javascript ONLY

Tags: javascript

Am new to javascript, am trying to achieve a situation where a class is toggled when I click on a list item from a group of list items in an  list. Am also adding items to the list dynamically, so if I click on any added list item a class is also toggled on it.

Here's my code. This is what I've tried so far.

var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

```
function toggleStrikethrough() {
    for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].classList.toggle("done"); 
    }
}

li[i].addEventListener("click", toggleStrikethrough);
```

I expect a line through when a list item is clicked and back to normal when clicked again.

Comment: This would add the "done" class to ALL li's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, you want to loop through the elements to add a click event:

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("LI"); // My preferred non-library way of getting the li's

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener("click", toggleStrikethrough);
}
```

Then, you want to change the *style* of the element of the `li`:

```
function toggleStrikethrough() {
    li[i].style = "text-decoration: line-through;";
    // Would need a toggle system 
    // For example, a variable and if statement
}
```

That's one way of approaching it, but [@Tim VN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56275942/how-to-toggle-a-css-class-on-list-items-when-a-click-event-is-triggered-using-ja/56276062#56276062) made an awesome answer too, so check that out.

Comment: This unfortunately won't work, so I'm puzzled as to why it's the best answer. Given that this function is put in the same script after the for-loop, ```i``` will always be 5, and thus out of bounds. It's also easier to simply toggle a class such as done, and avoid putting any CSS in your code directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for ... of loop and toggle the class as a callback of each of the event listeners:

```js
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var el of li) {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => e.target.classList.toggle("done"));
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixed up. You want the loop outside of the `toggleStrikeThrough` function, and add the event listeners there. The `toggleStrikeThrough` function simply has to toggle the `done` class.

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

function toggleStrikethrough() {
 this.classList.toggle("done");    
}

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
 li[i].addEventListener("click", toggleStrikethrough);
}
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```